# Node.js JSON.stringify variables not expanding

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am working on a node.js API for an app with a simple TCP server that accepts NDJSON (essentially delimited by '\r\n'). Anyway, I am having an issue with JSON stringify. I create an object (see below) with variables and then convert it to stringify. When I get the result, it's expanded all the variables except for "requestParamName." It's the only key, as opposed to being a value, and this is the result:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Client.SetVolume","id":0,"params":{"client":"00:00:00:00:00:00","requestParamName":10}}
```

It should be this:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Client.SetVolume","id":0,"params":{"client":"00:00:00:00:00:00","volume":10}}
```

I've tried several things, but I'm not sure what's causing it to not expand that particular variable. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd be grateful.

Function:

```
function ClientConnect(requestMethod, requestMacAddress, requestParamName, requestParamKey) {
    var objectRequest = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": requestMethod,
        "id": 0,
        "params": {
            "client": requestMacAddress,
            requestParamName: requestParamKey
        }};

    formattedJson = (JSON.stringify(objectRequest) + '\r\n');
    console.log(formattedJson);
}
```

P.S. I'm new here so if I messed up the formatting, I apologize ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually doing :

```
"params": {
        "client": requestMacAddress,
        requestParamName: requestParamKey
    }};
```

is exactly the same that :

```
"params": {
            "client": requestMacAddress,
            "requestParamName": requestParamKey
        }};
```

You have to do like this (note that it's an ES6 feature - it's ok if you use a recent node.js):

```
var objectRequest = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": requestMethod,
        "id": 0,
        "params": {
            "client": requestMacAddress,
            [requestParamName]: requestParamKey
        }};
```

The ES5 version will be:

```
var objectRequest = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": requestMethod,
        "id": 0,
        "params": {
            "client": requestMacAddress
        }};
objectRequest[requestParamName]= requestParamKey;
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know about the brackets thing. It worked perfectly! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

[variable] is what you need, otherwise it will be the same as above ^^

Comment: Could you please elaborate?